# How to perform specific actions for all collections in DB except for a specific collection using roles in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-security

I want to be able to read, insert, update, find and delete for the to-dos collection and for the users collection, I just want to find, insert and update. My first solution was:

```sh
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "all_permissions_except_user_delete",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "todo-fsharp-api", collection: "todos" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert", "remove" ] },
       { resource: { db: "todo-fsharp-api", collection: "users" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   },
   { w: "majority" }
)
```

This really works but it is not scalable because if I add another collection I cannot do anything with this new collection, unless I modified the role.

In short, I want to be able to carry out all the actions on the to-dos collection and future collections. Specifically for the users collection I want to do everything but delete.

I was thinking of something like this but it doesn't work, it still lets me delete users.

```sh
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "all_permissions_except_user_delete",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "todo-fsharp-api", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert", "remove" ] },
       { resource: { db: "todo-fsharp-api", collection: "users" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   },
   { w: "majority" }
)
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: May be create two roles - one for all collections and one for the "users".

Comment: That does not work. I think this is not possible.